# Get Woocommerce product reviews via rest api

Tags: rest, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I tried to get product reviews with rest api but I got an error `woocommerce_rest_cannot_view`

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/reviews?product=ID
```

I don't know where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

In some how it was an issue on woocommerce api

I edited the class-wc-rest-product-reviews.php

```
$prepared_args['type'] = 'review';
```

changed review to comment and it works